# Predefined type 'System.Object/String' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created the default ASP .NET Core MVC app in Visual Studio 2017 and there are 100+ errors and 44 warnings. The errors are:

1. Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
2. Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
3. Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported

I have tried these:
 - restart and reinstall VS 
 - delete the bin and obj folders
 - rebuild the project
 - dotnet restore reopen the project in VS

project: https://github.com/martin-petrov03/Demo/tree/master/Ex

Comment: Look at the least common error. If you got that many errors, something trips up the parsing so badly, it can not longer tell you where the error even is.

Comment: There are also some namespacing errors but the template is the default one. I can't understand why I have errors.

Comment: Namespace erros instantly explain errors like "What the bleep is a Object?" Fix those first, maybe it solves itself. Object is the root of **every** class heirarchy in .NET. If it is not found, nothing else has any hope of working.

Comment: I dont know how to fix them because the configuration is from visual studio and it should be correct.

Comment: When I open files the error number is getting bigger and bigger. Almost every line is underline

Comment: Then make a empty project and show us the code. Without code, there is nothing else we can do.

Comment: I talk about empty project with individual authentication. Can you tell me could the errors be due to .net core version / vs version  or something like that?

Comment: The code is the default one

Comment: **Show** us the code VS creates by default. That way we can figure out if there is anything wrong with the tempalte or the VS installation. If it is the default code, there is no reason to hide it. And every reason to show it.

Comment: Ok I committed in my github repo with name Demo. My profile is https://github.com/martin-petrov03

Comment: That's the code https://github.com/martin-petrov03/Demo/tree/master/Ex. Can you help?

Comment: If you insist on not giving use the details we are asking for, in the post as we are asking for, we will not be able to help you.

Comment: I can't understand what are you asking for. I have no reason no hide details or code.

Comment: Almost all errors are Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported on different lines in different files.

Comment: Intellisense may be broken, if so you may have to go to a different version of VS. Otherwise check that the target framework of your projects are correct under Properties.

Answer (score 6):

I recently experience the same.
I eventually fixed the issue by removing the offending projects from the solution and then re-adding them (you can actually just 'unload' them).

Answer (score 4):

I recently had this with an existing project with Visual Studio 2022. I had the project open last week no issue, this week I opened again to check some code and everything blew up red.

Unloading and reloading projects did not work for me initially. Nor did restarting Visual Studio. I did not try reinstalls - that is painful, and I assume I'll encounter this again someday.

What did work was this:

1. Right click on each project that was behaving this way and select **"Load Entire Dependency Tree"**
2. Right click on that project again and select **"Unload Project"**
3. Right click on that unloaded project and select **"Reload with Project Dependencies"**

Might be doable with less steps but I can't repro the issue so that's all I have for now!

Comment: Similar problem here on VS2019 Pro. It happened immediately after I added the Newtonsoft JSON Nuget package to my (Windows Forms) project.

Your steps 2 & 3 were sufficient to put it right.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem today too.
It turned out that adding this text:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

into my UWP .csproj caused the problem to go away

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue today. The issue i eventually tracked it down to was the follow had been added to the csproj.

Unsure what had added it, since it appeared between two builds, where no code/nuget package changes were made.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Private.CoreLib">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.14\System.Private.CoreLib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Deleted this from the csproj and the issue went away.